# MySQL returned an empty result for a date query

Tags: mysql, sql

When querying `MYSQL` for records in 'current_date' with today's date , 'No' data is returned for the queried date. Instead , It returning as

```
"MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows). ( Query took 0.0004 sec )"
```

Tried and None of the below queries returns any records.

**TRIED SQL QUERIES :**

```
SELECT hash FROM malware_db WHERE current_date like '%2017-07-10%'

SELECT hash FROM malware_db WHERE date(current_date) like '%2017-07-10%'
SELECT hash FROM malware_db WHERE date(current_date) between date('2017-07-10 00:00:00') AND date('2017-07-10 23:59:59')
```

**SAMPLE DB RECORDS**

```
hash,first_seen,last_seen,current_date,status,treat,trust,name,famil,generic,platform,subplatform,mType,scannerPercent

9dc1a6770bf57142bbfb9428b3e6213e,2014-06-10 22:01:00,2017-07-02 18:10:00,2017-07-10 23:06:23,MALICIOUS,5,5,Android.Exploit.Lotoor,Lotoor,False,Android,None,None,57.1428565979
```

In the structure , `Type` of the "`current_date`" column is "`datetime`" .

Not sure , What is the issue here ? Any suggestions please ?

Comment: `date(current_date) = curdate()` should work.

Comment: wrap the `current_date` in graves. like: `\`current_date\``. So, try this: SELECT hash FROM malware_db WHERE \`current_date\` like '%2017-07-10%

Comment: @Mojtaba Nope that doesn't help. Im getting "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''%2017-07-10%' at line 1" when passing "SELECT hash FROM malware_db WHERE `current_date` like '%2017-07-10%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select hash from malware_db where date(current_date) = date(now());
```

Comment: Thanks Raju. This will give me all the data but not the data only from '2017-07-10'.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT hash FROM malware_db WHERE DATE( current_date ) = '2017-07-10'
```

But it really sounds like you are not looking in the right DB/table, since all of these suggestions should work.